# Arduino reboot with DIY H-bridge Controller

Tags: relay, h-bridge, dpdt

Here is my already tested and working schematic of the DIR +PWM mode DIY H-bridge on DPDT relay with IRLB-3034 N-channel MOSFET with opto isolation from the controller, and some "quick gate" driver for the mosfet. What can be the reason of the controller reboot? From time to time. What can be done? 
The motor is working in the application with almost constant stall condition.

[image]

---

May I consult, wheather a relay snubber has the right connection?
[image]

Comment: Could be EMI coupled across the opto capacitance, or other stray paths.  Could even be radiated.  What's the supply for the controller, is it completely isolated from the 12V motor supply?  How's your decoupling on everything?  Have you tried a snubber across the relay contacts?

Comment: I also suppose the radiation for it. 12 v 12.5 A with 4 farad cap on parallel to PSU.  The thing is that it doesn't  want to operate without 12 Bat. as gate drive, grounds to be connected with a motor PSU. May be smth can be done with it? I check with caps on motor, but it eliminates the PWM. The snubber should be connected to the coil?

Comment: Oh, the controller is isolated from the motor power. Common only with gate driver bat and a motor psu. Return the the suppressions with cap on motor terminals and to motor body. I tested it without gate driver before and there were no pwm. Now it's ok. Will check with caps on terminal then more.

Comment: The snubber goes across the contacts, not the coil.  As the contacts make and break, the contact bounce and arcing can send out large amounts of EMI.  Google relay contact snubber and you  should get lots of info on that.

Comment: John, thank you so much!